# Format string in PHP

Tags: php

I have below code, which gets me file path as `voicetube/record/1985150721112615`
but I need only `1985150721112615` exploding first two folders,please help me on this

```
$sql = "SELECT filePath FROM user_recordings ORDER BY recordDate ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$var = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $var[] = $row['filePath'];
}
```

Comment: You can just split the string everytime there's a `/` and the question:"How to do that?", is definitely a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php);

```
   $var[] = basename($row['filePath']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, and grab it's last index.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $arr = explode('/', $row['filePath']);
    $var[] = $arr[count($arr) -1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine now